# How can I set up write-behind persistence in an Infinispan cache programmatically?

Tags: java, infinispan

I am trying to create a write-behind cache programmatically. I see it's possible to declare it in XML, but I don't see a Java method to declare write-behind parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
persistence
     .addSingleFileStore()
     .async().enable().modificationQueueSize(1000);
```